# How to fit my histogram to a curve without exactly knowing the underlying distribution in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have obtained a histogram using Monte carlo simulation of about 100000 samples. When I fit it to a normal distribution, the accuracy is extremely low. How to obtain a fit for my histogram?

[histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQrCM.png)

Comment: It looks to me like the left half of a (shifted) normal distribution. I would suggest to adjust your fitting function to a gaussian for the part left of the peak and 0 for the part right of it.

Comment: Is there a specific way to modify this using norm.fit?